# Tensorflow Federated : Why my iterative Process unable to train rounds

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I write a code with TFF from my own dataset, all the code run correctly except 
this line

In train_data, I make 4 dataset, loaded with tf.data.Dataset, they have the type "DatasetV1Adapter"

```
def client_data(n):
  ds = source.create_tf_dataset_for_client(source.client_ids[n])
  return ds.repeat(10).map(map_fn).shuffle(500).batch(20)

federated_train_data = [client_data(n) for n in range(4)]

batch = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x: x.numpy(), iter(train_data[0]).next())

def model_fn():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    .........
  return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(model, batch)
```

all this run correctly and I get trainer and state:

```
trainer = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)
```

Except, When I would to begin training and round with this code:

```
state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data) 
print('round  1, metrics={}'.format(metrics))
```

I can't. error comes! So, from where can be the error? from type of dataset? or the way that I make my data federated?

Comment: Could the question be extend to include the exact error message seen? From the code above it looks like the variable names differ: a `train_data` is created and later a `federated_train_data` is requested.

Comment: thanks for the remark , I corrected the inattention error. but my problem is that when executing the last line (first round), the kernel takes a lot of time (runs) but then it crashes without displaying anything.

Comment: Sounds like your machine may be running out of memory? Its hard to say without more information such as what does the input dataset look like, is the code running on CPU or GPU?

A few things to try to reduce memory footprint: test by running on only a single client (change `range(4)` to `range(1)` when building `federated_train_data`), reduce size of the `.shuffle()` buffer. Also calling `.batch()` before `.map()` on the data input pipeline, and using the `num_parallel_calls` argument, can vastly speed up data reading. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance is a good guide.

Comment: @ZacharyGarrett Please see the answer, I make the code

Answer (score 0):

here is my code, I use Tensorflow v2.1.0 and tff 0.12.0

```
img_height = 200
img_width = 200
num_classes = 2
batch_size = 10

input_shape = (img_height, img_width, 3)

img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
gen0 = img_gen.flow_from_directory(par1_train_data_dir,(200, 200),'rgb', batch_size=10)
ds_par1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
    output_shapes=([None,img_height,img_width,3], [None,num_classes])
)
ds_par2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen0 
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
    output_shapes=([None,img_height,img_width,3], [None,num_classes])
)

dataset_dict={}
dataset_dict['1'] = ds_par1
dataset_dict['2'] = ds_par2

def create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn(client_id):
    return dataset_dict[client_id]

source = tff.simulation.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn(['1','2'],create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn)

def client_data(n):
  ds = source.create_tf_dataset_for_client(source.client_ids[n])
  return ds


train_data = [client_data(n) for n in range(1)]

images, labels = next(img_gen.flow_from_directory(par1_train_data_dir,batch_size=batch_size,target_size=(img_height,img_width)))
sample_batch = (images,labels)

def create_compiled_keras_model():
  .....

def model_fn():
    keras_model = create_compiled_keras_model()
    return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, sample_batch)

iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)
state = iterative_process.initialize()


state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, train_data)
print('round 1, metrics={}'.format(round_num, metrics))
```

Comment: Could you try adding a `take(100)` to your client_data function? IE, `return ds.take(100)` instead of just `return ds`? I am wondering if this is silently creating an infinite dataset.

Comment: What's that supposed to mean take(100)? is it batch_size? If yes, I can remove batch_size from generator and make it here?

Comment: Thank you very much, it is a point that helped me, But I have umbalanced dataset, meaning that not all client has the same quantity of data(each has 700 images, othar has 200 images...) So in this case how I can fix N, because Take(N) applied for every entrie in the function

Answer (score 0):

As verified in the comments above, adding a `take(N)` call for some finite integer `N` in the `client_data` function should solve this problem. The issue is that TFF will reduce over *all the elements in the dataset you pass it*. If you have an infinite dataset, this means "keep running the reduction forever". `N` here should represent "how much data an individual client has", and can really be anything of your choosing.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is a point that helped me, But I have umbalanced dataset, meaning that not all client has the same quantity of data(each has 700 images, othar has 200 images...) So in this case how I can fix  `N`, because  `Take(N) ` applied for every entrie in the function